# Login to a spotify account using libspotify on windows?

Tags: windows, authentication, spotify, account, libspotify

My problem is that I can enter login credentials that aren't correct but I still get a successful login. My code looks like this. Even If I just slam on the keyboard for my username and password, it still tells me that I have successfully logged in.

```
void CreateSession()
{
    memset(&config, 0, sizeof(config));

    config.api_version = SPOTIFY_API_VERSION;
    config.cache_location = "tmp";
    config.settings_location = "tmp";
    config.application_key = g_appkey;
    config.application_key_size = g_appkey_size;
    config.user_agent = "SpotifyTest";

    error = sp_session_create(&config, &session);
    qDebug() << "1";
    if (SP_ERROR_OK != error)
    {
        qDebug() << "failed to create session: " << sp_error_message(error);
        return;
    }
}

void Login(char* username, char* password)
{

    char *blob = NULL;
    if(session == NULL)
    { 
        CreateSession();
        qDebug() << "Session Created";
    }
    error = sp_session_login(session, username, password, 1, blob);
    if (SP_ERROR_OK != error)
    {
        qDebug() << "failed to log in to Spotify: " << sp_error_message(error);
        sp_session_release(session);
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Successful Login";
        QString user_name = sp_session_user_name(session);
        qDebug() << user_name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The return value from `sp_session_login()` just tells you whether you sent valid input to the function.

To actually tell if login is successful, you need to implement the callbacks in `sp_session_callbacks`, specifically `logged_in`, `logged_out` and `connection_error`.

The sample projects that come with libspotify contain implementations of this.